# Feynman Path Integral as a Quantization Scheme

Tags: path-integral, quantization

Why isn't the [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) usually discussed as a quantization scheme, like geometric and deformation quantization? Was searching wikipedia for this.

Comment: What do you mean *"it isn't discussed"*? It is indeed discussed as the *main* (if not) quantisation scheme in any standard textbook (I would be very careful in using Wikipedia when it comes to physics).

Comment: The non-relativistic path integral that Feynman suggested originally is a way to solve the Schroedinger equation. Up to serious and non-trivial mathematical convergence issues they are different descriptions (one PDG, one integral based) of the   same physics. The path integral offers an interesting insight into what "a classical particle would have to do" in order to behave like a quantum system, so in that sense you can look at it as an additional interpretation of QM, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to asking why the Schrödinger equation isn't a quantization scheme- the path integral is simply a way to obtain the propagator for a state, just like the Schrödinger equation.  In geometric or deformation quantization of a symplectic manifold, we are, in general, trying to obtain a noncommutative algebra of observables from the original "classical" commutative algebra of observables.

The path integral has purpose only after quantization.  You can see this because the action $S$ for any path $\lambda$ depends on the lagrangian, which is itself a function of quantized unitary operators.